# Is Fade In/Out Animation Broken?

Tags: android, android-animation, fade

I am getting some very weird behaviors with Android Animations and I want to understand what's going on.

My `ImageView` is invisible at xml and I am not setting the `alpha`.

#### This code was supposed to Fade In/Out makes my `ImageView` but it doesn't animate anything and goes straight to the end effect:

```
if (isFadeIn) {
    myImage.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(5000).withStartAction(() -> {
        myImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        myImage.setAlpha(0.0f);
    });
} else {
    myImage.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(5000)
      .withEndAction(() -> myImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE));
}
```

#### Now this code Fades In and Out.....BUT the first time it runs it doesn't Fade In, and Fade Out always blinks:

```
if (isFadeIn) {
    myImage.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(5000).withStartAction(() -> {
        myImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        myImage.setAlpha(0.0f);
    }).withEndAction(() -> myImage.setAlpha(1.0f));
} else {
    myImage.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(5000)
            .withStartAction(() -> {
                myImage.setAlpha(1.0f);
                myImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            })
      .withEndAction(() -> myImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE));
}
```

I am cracking my head for hours trying to understand why those behaviors are arising.

#### Now, This code works:

```
fadeInAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        myImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) { }
    @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
});

fadeOutAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
    @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        myImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
});

fadeInAnimation.setDuration(5000);
fadeOutAnimation.setDuration(5000);

...

if (isFadeIn) {
    myImage.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);
} else {                         
    myImage.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
}
```

But it's too verbose, I don't like it, but for now I am sticking with it, I just wanted to understand what's wrong with the other code.

Comment: As I understood, animation behavior ambiguous in only first time. Most probably your animation timer start when your screen binding. That's why you only see last half of your animation

Comment: What do you mean by `ambiguous`? The animation that doesn't work the first time is just the Fade In. After the first Fade Out it works just fine

Comment: I mean unpredictable behavior. Just forget about it. I wanted to say your animation timer started before you see it the first time. That's why you see last part of animation at the first time.

Comment: My animation is set to take 5 seconds, even if the timer started before, it would take a long time to finish and I should still see it.

Comment: It might not be an exact problem. But try it. You can check it by changing it like 20sec

Comment: It can't be because other animations run just fine and they are triggered at the same point than the first Fade In

Comment: Even if it was... How to fix it?

Comment: It's really good if you can trigger it after any button click or event fire. But you want to do it initially. moved it to bottom of onCreate() method

Comment: It does trigger after a button click